# Why does Torch computation operation call DtoH memcpy?

Tags: python, pytorch

Here's a code example.

```
import torch
import torch.cuda.nvtx as nvtx_cuda

A = torch.rand(size=(1024*4, 1024*4), device="cuda")
B = torch.rand(size=(1024*4, 1024*4), device="cuda")
C = torch.rand(size=(1024*4, 1024*4), device="cuda")
D = torch.rand(size=(1024*4, 1024*4), device="cuda")
E = torch.rand(size=(1024*4, 1024*4), device="cuda")
F = torch.rand(size=(1024*4, 1024*4), device="cuda")

torch.cuda.cudart().cudaProfilerStart()

idx_mask = torch.rand(1024, device="cuda")
active_idx = torch.rand(1024, device="cuda")
nvtx_cuda.range_push("S0")
active_idx = torch.nonzero(idx_mask, as_tuple=True)
nvtx_cuda.range_pop()

nvtx_cuda.range_push("S1")
C = A.matmul(B)
F = D.matmul(E)
nvtx_cuda.range_pop()

print(active_idx)

torch.cuda.cudart().cudaProfilerStop()
```

Regarding the code, I'm very curious about why `active_idx = torch.nonzero(idx_mask, as_tuple=True)` calls CudaMemcpyAsync.

Here're my points.

- `idx_mask` and `active_idx` are both on the GPU first.
- So, all operations should be conducted on a GPU (independent of the CPU).
- I suspect that the python `torch.nonzero` calls a CUDA kernel that does a non-zero operation in C++ within its underneath code because, in any way, the kernel should be called by the CPU thread. For example, GPU should send something like a pointer to the CPU, and the CPU launches the kernel.
- So I make an example that calls a GEMM kernel, but that kernel does not call any memory operation (This also does the GEMM operation for tensors on a GPU).
- In summary, what I want to do is eliminate the memory operation (GPU->CPU), making it independent of the CPU or at least make it to be a non-blocking operation which means eliminating the cudaSyncThread (the green block in the figure).

[image]
This is a non-zero operation.

[image]
This is a GEMM kernel.

**Please note that the cudaMemasync is not called by the GEMM kernel in Figure 2.**

Comment: Surely that is a question for the Pytorch developers to answer? Also why not just go and read the Pytorch source for the routine you are interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nonzero.html#torch.nonzero

In this doc, it needs to synchronize when the tensor is in the GPU.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).